# Is the reason fot the error object slicing?

Tags: c++, dynamic, vector, std, object-slicing

```
g++ -std=gnu++0x main.cpp
In file included from main.cpp:6:0:
CustArray.h: In constructor 'CustArray::CustArray()':
CustArray.h:26:32: error: 'class Info' has no member named 'someInfo'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

```
/*
 * Info.h
 *
 */

#ifndef INFO_H_
#define INFO_H_

class Info
{
    friend class CustArray;
};

#endif /* INFO_H_ */


/*
 * SubInfo.h
 *
 */

#include "Info.h"

class SubInfo : public Info
{

const int someInfo;

public:
    SubInfo(const int someInfo):someInfo(someInfo){}
};

#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include "Info.h"
#include "SubInfo.h"

template<typename T>
struct ptrModel
{
    typedef std::unique_ptr<T> Type;
};

//Alias shortener.
typedef ptrModel<Info>::Type ptrType;

class CustArray
{

protected:
    std::vector<ptrType> array;

public:
    CustArray()
    {
        ptrType el_init(new SubInfo(1));
        array.push_back(std::move(el_init));
        int someInfo = (*(array[0])).someInfo;
    }

};

/*
 * main.cpp
 *
 */

#include "CustArray.h"
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    CustArray seq;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Base> >` is just that: a vector filled with pointers to bases. And ***you cannot access derived class' content through base class pointers/references*** - even if objects of derived classes are behind those pointers/references.

This is no different from this:

```
SubInfo si(1); 
Info& info = si;
info.someInfo; // won't compile
```

That doesn't mean that behind `info` there isn't a derived class' object. There is. But ***you  cannot access anything of it but what's available through the base class interface***. That's basic OO.

Answer (score 1):

No, you have a pointer to the base class `Info`, which as the compiler says, doesn't have a member named `someInfo`.  That pointer still points to a `SubInfo`, but you can't access derived class members through a base class pointer.

If you really need access to the field, you would need to use `dynamic_cast` to downcast.  Be sure to check the result to ensure the cast is valid.

Answer (score 1):

What it's saying is true

`error: 'class Info' has no member named 'someInfo'`

It doesn't. You can not access child members in a polymorphic way like you are attempting.

You will need a virtual member function in the class Info such as `GetSomeInfo()` which can either be pure virtual or return something interesting in the base class. Then in the child class it can return `someInfo`